# Zoom desktop app settings do not save

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, zoom

The Zoom desktop app isn't saving settings between restarts, no matter which instance I use (website install, AUR, Flatpak). What do I need to do?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but please tell us what operating system you are using, if Linux, which one, which version of Zoom this refers to, and other details. I am guessing you are using Arch, since you mention AUR, but it would be nice to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the **`~/.zoom`** directory in my home folder worked for me